# How to enter data into Excel through HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Recently I have been asked by my school to create a website that will among other things have the ability to do online sign ups that will enter data into an excel spreadsheet for someone to open and read. The main goal is to use this for merchandise, sports teams, and events and replace our current paper sign ups.

The website will only be available on our school intranet and will be hosted somewhere in the network storage. On our computers, we're stuck with Internet Explorer.

I don't know how to store values into an Excel Spreadsheet, how can I do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

By a little bit of search on google you can find out what is the best suits for you. There is a lot of Javascript Plugins to do that. 
this is the good one you may have check on it: [ExcelPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/)